# get all choices from Select input and save it as a vector

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a select input As following:

UI.R

```
ui <- fluidPage(

              selectInput("state", "State",choices=c("within becnhamrk","out of Benchmark")),

              selectInput("Action","Actions",choices=c("choose number of wokers precisely","choose arbitrarily the amount workers","Use Experinced supplier","Use The nearest Supplier")),
              fileInput('file2', 'Upload Probability Matrix',accept=c('.csv','.xlsx')),
              actionButton("submit6", "Add",icon = icon("plus-circle"),class = "btn-primary")
            )),
```

I want to get all choices of selectInput with the Id of state and save it as a separate vector.

Server.R

```
observe({
  states<-reactive({
    c(input$state)})

})
```

How can I save all choices of state in a vector without user selection?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, you want `action` to be the value the user has not selected? Also no need to wrap a reactive expression in an `observe`

Comment: I want to save all choices of sate as a vector and then reuse it in some other function.

Comment: So in this case you want `actions` to be `c("within becnhamrk","out of Benchmark")`?

Comment: no I want states be c("within becnhamrk","out of Benchmark") , and actions  be c("choose number of wokers precisely","choose arbitrarily the amount workers","Use Experinced supplier","Use The nearest Supplier") in 2 different vectors

Comment: I am sorry I have corrected my mistake yes you were right , It was actions now I changed it to states

Comment: So they are not reactive? If so, just define `actions<-c("choose number of wokers precisely","choose arbitrarily the amount workers","Use Experinced supplier","Use The nearest Supplier")` and `states<-c("within becnhamrk","out of Benchmark")` in a file named `global.R`, in the same directory where `server.R` and `ui.R` are. Then you can use them wherever you want in your shiny app.

Comment: Thanks It works,  so if I define any object in global.r that object will be global and it can be reuse in any function, Am I right?